# Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'MultiSelect Module'

Tags: angular, primeng

Getting compiliation error as,

> Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'MultiSelect Module'

while updating the primeng version from 6 to 7.

Even i have installed angular:

```
cdk npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

Still the error exist..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please learn about the technology stack you are using and correct the tagging

Comment: fixed by updating:-@angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.6","primeng": "^7.0.5","@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.6", "karma": "^4.0.0", "typescript": "^3.2.4"